# Starting SQL server replication from .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-replication

I'm working on a program to manage replications between a number of databases. I've run in to a strange error running one of the procs from C# though and just can't figure it out.

In step one everyting is OK:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_replicationdboption", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", masterDbName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optname", "publish");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "true");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Step 2 gives me the error message "Error creating replication: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction. The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction."

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_addlogreader_agent", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_login", @"domain\userId");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_password", "password");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher_security_mode", "1");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However running the same stored procedure from Management Studio works.

```
exec sp_addlogreader_agent @job_login='domain\user', 
                           @job_password='password', 
                           @publisher_security_mode='1';
```

**Edit:** When I wrap the stored procedure in a transaction I get the error message "The procedure 'sp_replicationdboption' cannot be executed within a transaction". I'm confused,

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! When calling the proc from C# I had to run it under the Windows account, not the SQL Server account, so this worked:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_addlogreader_agent", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher_security_mode", "1");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher_login", @"domain\userId");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher_password", "password");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error message could have been a bit more helpful!